# How do I make a 3.5mm combo jack work with Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, microphone

I have an HP Spectre X360, which has a headset/microphone combo jack built in. I have a headset/microphone earbud system built by Seinhauser. It works correctly on my Android phone, but when I plug it into my Linux machine, Pavucontrol does not recognize the microphone and the microphone records nothing.

Nixos-16.09
Pulseaudio 9.0-rebootstrapped

This is what I see on the inputs tab whether the headset is plugged in or not:

[image]

When plugged in, though, I see this on the outputs tab:

[image]

This model is known to have a problem with Linux and built-in sound, but sound *playback* is resolved with a grub stanza that I already have working: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/HP-spectre-x360-on-linux/m-p/5122160#M66839

I would very much like to get the input working, because the handset microphone is much more resilient against ambient sound than the in-screen microphone, and bluetooth microphones don't seem to work with pulseaudio any more ([How do I fix HSP/HFP bluetooth profiles on linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1155496/how-do-i-fix-hsp-hfp-bluetooth-profiles-on-linux)).

Comment: Intel HDA soundscards can have a quite complex configuration, and if you need ACPI boot parameters, ACPI is likely still broken to some degree. Do `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` to show this configuration, so you have some idea what the hardware does. If necessary, you can use [hda-jack-retask](http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2011/11/29/turn-your-mic-jack-into-a-headphone-jack/) to force some "pins" to input.